# Trouble looping a multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array. It contains nicknames and names:

```
$nickAndNames = array( 
    array( "Johnie", "John Larson" ),
    array ("Maggie", "Margaret London" ),
    array("Nic","Nicholas Carradine")
);
```

Can you please help me to print just the first elements? I mean Johnie, Maggie, Nic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each element of the array is another array. Each element of this inner array in turn contains 2 elements: element 0 (a string, the nickname) and element 1 (another string, the name). Therefore, you'd first need to loop through the `$nicksAndNames` array, and then display the inner array's first element (which is element 0):

```
// loop through $nickAndNames and assign, in turn, each inner array
// to a variable named $nickAndName
foreach ($nickAndNames as $nickAndName) {
    // this $nickAndName variable now contains the inner array, something like:
    // array("Johnie", "John Larson"), so "Johnie" is the first element,
    // element 0
    echo $nickAndName[0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop to go through the array and then print the first element, index `0`.

```
$nickAndNames = array( 
    array( "Johnie", "John Larson" ),
    array ("Maggie", "Margaret London" ),
    array("Nic","Nicholas Carradine")
);

foreach ($nickAndNames as $name) {
    echo $name[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will loop through all of the names:

```
foreach( $nickAndNames as $data)
    echo $data[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

look here:

```
foreach ($nickAndNames as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($value[0]);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This should give you something to work with:

```
foreach ($nickAndNames as $person)
{
    reset($person); // May not be needed.
    print current($person);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you could correct your array with a properly named key value pair like below,

```
$nickAndNames = array( 
         array( "nickname" => "Johnie", "name" => "John Larson" ),
         array ("nickname" => "Maggie", "name" => "Margaret London" ),
         array("nickname" => "Nic","name" => "Nicholas Carradine")
         );
```

You can do

```
foreach($nickAndNames as $nickAndName){
    if(is_array($nickAndName))
    {
        foreach($nickAndName as $nN)
        {
             echo 'nickname = '. $nN['nickname'];
             echo 'name = '. $nN['name'];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'nickname = '. $nN['nickname'];
        echo 'name = '. $nN['name'];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps,

Karthik